# SEGV_MAPERR Error in PubNub Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault, pubnub

Following code is throwing a segv_maperr error, Problem is that error is only showing in splunk logs of my live application. But I am not able to reproduce it. Need guidance on what could be causing this ?

```
PubNub.requestPushNotificationEnabledChannelsForDevicePushToken(dToken,
            withCompletionHandlingBlock: { (channels, error) -> Void in
            if let pnChannels = channels as? [PNChannel] {
                if (!pnChannels.contains(self.myChannel))
                {
                    PubNub.enablePushNotificationsOnChannel(self.myChannel,
                        withDevicePushToken: dToken, andCompletionHandlingBlock: { (array, error2) -> Void in
                    })
                }
            }
            else
            {
                PubNub.enablePushNotificationsOnChannel(self.myChannel,
                    withDevicePushToken: dToken, andCompletionHandlingBlock: { (array, error2) -> Void in
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you send details and full code to support@pubnub.com. We can post back final issue/answer here. Thanks

Comment: Can you try to use latest PubNub client version?